# Replacing a blank

Tags: python

i am building a URL and replacing all the spaces with +

```
url.replace(' ','+')
```

for some reason it is not replacing any of the white spaces!

anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code. Can you paste more of your file, maybe you got something related wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The replace function doesn't replace anything in-place - you need to assign it:

```
url = url.replace(' ','+')
```

Comment: That is because string is immutable. If you have many changes to strings it is useful to make them lists by list(mystring) to avoid too much copying.

Comment: tony, can you elaborate please on what you just said

Answer (score 2):

You are probbly still looking at the old url. replace returns new string with replaced values. Try:

```
url = url.replace(' ', '+')
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside:

If you are encoding a query or path component for inclusion in a URL, you will need to do more than simply replacing the space character. There are *many* other characters which won't fit unencoded into a URL component, and which may break the URL if you try. These have to be replaced by `%nn` hexadecimal escape sequences.

Use `urllib` to take care of URL-encoding rather than trying to do it yourself with string methods. For example:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> param= 'Hello world!'
>>> url= 'http://www.example.com/script.py?a='+urllib.quote_plus(param)
>>> url
'http://www.example.com/script.py?a=Hello+world%21'
```

([`urllib.quote_plus()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus) is designed explicitly for form parameters in the query string, so it'll use `+` for spaces, as opposed to `%20` which `urllib.quote()` produces. `%20` works in path components as well as query components, so it's a bit safer than `+`, but slightly more messy visually.)

If you have more than one parameter, use [`urlencode()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) on a dictionary. This is generally easier to read than trying to stick strings together:

```
>>> params= {'foo': 'bar', 'bof': 'Hello world!'}
>>> url= 'http://www.example.com/script.py?'+urllib.urlencode(params)
>>> url
'http://www.example.com/script.py?foo=bar&bof=Hello+world%21'
```